# Show that $\int f\ge 3/2$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I'm trying to prove a question of my homework, but I'm stuck. The question is

> Question: let $f:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, such that $|f'(x)| < 1, \forall x$ and $f(0) = 2$, prove that $\int_0^1f(x)dx \geq \frac{3}{2}$

Ok, so my efforts until now were these:

1. I know that if $|f'(x)| < 1$, can be proved that $f(x)-f(y) < |x-y|$, (I don't prove that inequality is strictly), so I can use the condition on hypothesis $\Rightarrow$ $|f(x)-2| \leq |f(x)| -2 < |x|$ $\Rightarrow$ $\int_0^1f(x)dx < \int_0^1x-2dx$, so I only can conclude that $\int_0^1f(x)dx < 5/2$.
2. My other try is to using the mean value theorem so I can write down $f'(c) = \frac{f(1) - f(0)}{1-0} <1$, for some $c \in (a,b)$, then $f(1) < 3$.

I'm not sure about my first effort, but I'm confident about the second one.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Do you mean $|f'(x)|<1?$ In other case it is false: $f(x)=2-4x.$

Comment: @mfl Exactly my comment, you got there first

Comment: Yes, sorry guys

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are on the right way. We have that

$$|f(x)-f(0)|\le x.$$

**Edit**

Because of the mean value theorem for $x\in (0,1]$ we have that there exist $c\in (0,x)$ such that $f(x)-f(0)=f'(c)(x-0).$ Thus we have

$$|f(x)-2|=|f'(c)||x|<|x|.$$

**End**

Thus, it is

$$2-x\le f(x)\le 2+x.$$ (Note that the useful inequality here is $2-x\le f(x)$ and not $f(x)\le 2+x$.)

Integrantig over $[0,1]$ we have

$$2-\dfrac12\le \int_0^1 f(x)dx$$ and we are done.

Comment: Can you think and way to prove this exercise just using mean value theorem?

Comment: The first inequality is obtained using the mean value theorem. I have editted the answer to give more details.

Answer (score 1):

fou can also prove it in this way
We know that $f^{'}(x)>-1$ and $f(0) = 2$

$f(x) = f(0)+\int_{0}^{x}f^{'}(t)\,dt$

so

$f(x)>f(0) + \int_{0}^{x}-1\,dt$

$f(x)>2-x$

$\int_{0}^{1}f(x)dx >\int_{0}^{1}2-x\,dx=1.5$

This image is also an explanation:
[image: Geometric Viewpoint]